# Не обновился код на второй машине после commit и push на первой

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

Всем доброго времени суток. Только начал работать с git, поэтому если вопрос глупый - попрошу не пинать. 
Вопрос такой. Поднял себе репозиторий на домашней машине, пишу программку в нём. На рабочей машине через SSH клонирую этот же репозиторий, пишу код, делаю commit и push.  Приезжаю домой, запускаю Eclipse чтобы продолжить писать код, но история коммитов обновилась, а вот сам код - нет, файлы кода не изменились. Разработка ведется в одной ветке(программка не особо сложная), если это важно. Я, конечно, могу накатывать версии файлов кода из коммитов(в Eclipse - replace from commit), но хотелось бы, чтобы это делалось автоматически, то есть, написал код на рабочей машине, сделал commit и push - и вуаля, на домашней машине история коммитов обновилась и файлы проекта синхронизировались. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: судя по всему, нужны hooks (с которыми я сам до сих пор не ознакомился): http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git

Comment: Я бегло просматривал этот ресурс, обратил внимание на hooks, но не увидел(может, плохо посмотрел) команду, которая реализует как раз Эклипсовское replace from commit. Полагаю, что именно на ней всё и будет завязано: принять коммиты, просмотреть файлы, которые в нём менялись и заменить локальные файлы версией из коммита. То же самое сделать на стороне клиента при pull или клонировании репозитория.

UPD: А команда checkout часом не приводит ли версию файлов с кодом к состоянию на какой-либо коммит? То есть, например, checkout HEAD накатит версию файлов проекта в состояние на последний коммит.

Comment: @Yuri_Prime, скорее всего, нужен именно чекаут (текущее состояние файлов может отличаться от текущего состояния репы), другое дело, что я не знаю что будет с несохраненными изменениями.

Comment: я бы завел отдельную "репу", в которой работал с двух мест. Да, на домашнем компе будет две копии репозитория, но всех этих проблем не будет. Также можно завести на bitbucket.org репозиторий (там можно завести приватные).

Answer (score 1):

> Разработка ведется в одной ветке

Если вы используете удаленный репозиторий то у вас как минимум 2 ветки - master и origin/master

> но история коммитов обновилась, а вот сам код - нет

Какой командой обновлялись pull или fetch?

> хотелось бы, чтобы это делалось автоматически, то есть, написал код на рабочей машине, сделал commit и push - и вуаля, на домашней машине история коммитов обновилась и файлы проекта синхронизировались. Возможно ли такое?

Для этого вам нужно настроить автоматический запуск git pull по расписанию в то время когда вы едете с работы домой. Но у этого способа есть "подводный камень" - если дома останутся незаPUSHенные коммиты то история будет отличаться от той что на сервере.

Comment: Обновлялся командой Pull, она падала с ошибкой Nothing to fetch. В итоге поступил согласно совету @KoVadim, использую на домашней машине два набора репозиториев